# multi module app with kotlin kts - error running app in emulator (warning: default scripting plugin is disabled:)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am facing the error below whenever i try to run my first but big leap into android development and kotlin with a multimodule app similar to Now in Android demo app

```
warning: default scripting plugin is disabled: The provided plugin org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.ScriptingCompilerConfigurationComponentRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler
error: unable to evaluate script, no scripting plugin loaded
```

I have tried using android studio iguana and hedgehog but both gave same error.

For my first app, I have followed the structure of the now in android app.

kindly assist in making sense and resolving the error above.

my lips.versions.toml [versions only]

```
[versions]
accompanist = "0.32.0"
android-gradlePlugin = "8.1.4"
androidxCore = "1.12.0"
junit4 = "4.13.2"
androidx-test-ext-junit = "1.1.5"
espresso-core = "3.5.1"
lifecycle-runtime-ktx = "2.6.1"
activity-compose = "1.7.2"
androidxComposeBom = "2023.01.00"
androidDesugarJdkLibs = "2.0.3"
androidxAppCompat = "1.6.1"
androidxActivity = "1.8.0"
androidxBrowser = "1.6.0"
androidxComposeCompiler = "1.4.5"
androidxComposeMaterial3 = "1.1.0-alpha06"
androidxComposeRuntimeTracing = "1.0.0-alpha01"
androidxCoreSplashscreen = "1.0.1"
androidxDataStore = "1.0.0"
androidxEspresso = "3.5.1"
androidxLifecycle = "2.6.2"
androidxMacroBenchmark = "1.2.0-rc02"
androidxMetrics = "1.0.0-alpha04"
androidxNavigation = "2.7.4"
androidxProfileinstaller = "1.3.1"
androidxStartup = "1.1.1"
androidxTestCore = "1.5.0"
androidxTestExt = "1.1.5"
androidxTestRules = "1.5.0"
androidxTestRunner = "1.5.2"
androidxTracing = "1.1.0"
androidxUiAutomator = "2.2.0"
androidxWindowManager = "1.1.0"
androidxWork = "2.9.0-beta01"
coil = "2.4.0"
firebaseBom = "32.3.1"
firebaseCrashlyticsPlugin = "2.9.9"
firebasePerfPlugin = "1.4.2"
gmsPlugin = "4.4.0"
googleOss = "17.0.1"
googleOssPlugin = "0.10.6"
androidxHiltNavigationCompose = "1.0.0"
hilt = "2.44.2"
hiltExt = "1.0.0"
jacoco = "0.8.7"
kotlin = "1.8.20"
kotlinxCoroutines = "1.7.3"
kotlinxDatetime = "0.4.1"
kotlinxSerializationJson = "1.6.0"
ksp = "1.8.20-1.0.11"
lint = "31.1.2"
okhttp = "4.11.0"
protobuf = "3.24.4"
protobufPlugin = "0.9.4"
retrofit = "2.9.0"
retrofitKotlinxSerializationJson = "1.0.0"
room = "2.5.2"
secrets = "2.0.1"
turbine = "1.0.0"
ui-tooling = "1.4.3"
material = "1.9.0"
robolectric = "4.10.3"
roborazzi = "1.5.0"
paletteKtx = "1.0.0"
material3Android = "1.2.0-alpha12"



[bundles]
```

Action: Ran the app build.gradle.kts from within the file explorer,

expected: after successful build, app should be displayed in emulator

Actual:

```
warning: default scripting plugin is disabled: The provided plugin org.jetbrains.kotlin.scripting.compiler.plugin.ScriptingCompilerConfigurationComponentRegistrar is not compatible with this version of compiler
error: unable to evaluate script, no scripting plugin loaded
```

Comment: Hey  Can you include the build.gradle.kts of the project and build.gradle.kts of each module?

Comment: @stoyan_vuchev I will upload the files to the google drive path below;
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15JBZSnIvvoFRRfiTkclQKFLYURt-5q_o?usp=drive_link

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the support for compose is not enabled. It is required for each module containing compose logic to have compose enabled with a specified compiler version in the module `build.gradle.kts` configuration:

```kotlin
// Enable support for Compose.
buildFeatures {
    compose = true
}

// Specify the Compose compiler version.
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = libs.versions.androidxComposeCompiler.get()
}
```

Since you're using a version catalog, it makes sense to declare the compose compiler version there. I highly recommend updating the version of the dependencies (incl. kotlin, ksp, hilt, and many more), unless you have a certain requirements preventing you from doing so.

As of writing:

- The latest (stable) compose compiler version is 1.5.6
- The latest compose build of materials (BOM) version is 2023.10.01

Links to the official release notes:

- [Compose compiler](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler)
- [Compose BOM](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/bom/bom-mapping)

```ini
[versions]

# ...

kotlin = "1.9.21"
ksp = "1.9.21-1.0.5"
hilt = "2.49"
hiltExt = "1.1.0"
room = "2.6.1"

# ...

androidxComposeBom = "2023.10.01"
androidxComposeCompiler = "1.5.6"

# ...
```

Let me know if this fixes the issue.

Comment: Thanks @stoyan_vuchev for looking into this.
Within the build-logic project, there are classes which are used to define common dependencies based on plugins in modules and features.
Within these there compose = true config has been defined.

As I am quite new to android dev and gradle, I am unable to tinker with the versions as I did previously upgrade but led to broken modules and features.

I am however able to use the gradle docked panel to run the project which seems odd

Answer (score 0):

I eventually settled for using the "Run" button on the ide.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to run the application.

The following steps worked for me
**(Android Studio Iguana | 2023.2.1 Patch 1)**

1. Open up "`\.idea\workspace.xml`" file under your project
2. Search the "`workspace.xml`" file for "RunManager". The  tag in the XML file looked like this:

**Changed the XML to as shown below:**

```
  <component name="RunManager" selected="Android App.app">
    <configuration name="app" type="AndroidRunConfigurationType" factoryName="Android App">
```

**Another option for Step 2** is
to delete the "selected" attribute and the IDE's auto update feature will add the correct "selected" attribute to the "component" tag.

3. Then perform this -> "clean project", "build project" and "run" the application and the error went away. App started running from the IDE.